# Does eating high cholesterol foods impact cholesterol blood levels of 30% of population based on Web MD article?

Tags: nutrition, cholesterol

1. [This Web MD article suggests that 30% people are vulnerable to dietary cholesterol](http://www.webmd.com/food-recipes/features/cholesterol-food).

> Indeed, studies suggest that only about 30% of people are particularly susceptible to the effects of dietary cholesterol on blood cholesterol levels.

2. [This answer suggests no connection](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/16765/is-dietary-cholesterol-related-to-blood-serum-cholesterol).
3. [These US government dietary guidelines (page 76) suggests](http://www.health.gov/dietaryguidelines/dga2010/DietaryGuidelines2010.pdf) it is safe to consume <300 mg (a little bit more that in 1 egg) of dietary cholesterol a day.

Which of these options are scientifically accepted? And is there any contradiction in these three different viewpoints?

Comment: "How" questions don't work well here. This question would be OK if worded like this: "does dietary cholesterol affect blood cholesterol?"

Comment: @Oddthinking that is what I was talking about in chat yesterday .. the duplication of questions on cholesterol intake and effect on blood levels.

Comment: @Oddthinking I made update to the question. Please, remove **duplicate** flag.

Comment: -1: The claim is too vague. The existing answer (and answers to the "duplicate" question show that it has *some* effect on *all* people, but whether they are "particularly susceptible" to the "effects" is rather meaningless.

Answer (score 3):

This meta-analysis from 1992 by Hopkins of 76 trials where food was supplied by a metabolic kitchen nicely answers this question. [1]

[image: cholesterol kinetics]

The rise in cholestrol on consuming cholesterol is closely tied to the baseline consumption of dietary cholesterol. So, you can see that if you're on a plant based diet ( or vegan ), with zero cholesterol intake, then consuming an egg containing 250 mg of cholesterol will raise your serum cholesterol by about 0.35 mmol/L (13.5 mg/dl) but if you're on an average american diet of 400 mg/day of cholesterol, then the rise is only 0.1 mmol/L (3.9 mg/dl).  This is the reason why many studies were confused by the effect of eggs on dietary cholesterol as they didn't understand the relationship between baseline intake and added consumption.

I haven't read link 3 above, but usually dietary guidelines advise that you don't exceed your cholesterol intake by 300 mg/day but they do not advise that you should consume cholesterol. There is no biological need to consume cholesterol since we manufacture all of our requirements in the liver.

---

[1] Hopkins PN. [Effects of dietary cholesterol on serum cholesterol: a meta-analysis and review.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1534437) Am. J. Clin. Nutr. 1992 Jun;55(6):1060-70. PubMed PMID: 1534437. [Full text](http://ajcn.nutrition.org/content/55/6/1060.long)

Comment: Could you provide reference for FIG 2?

Comment: It's at the bottom of my answer.  Full text is also available.

Comment: It's only abstract available in the link you provided.

Comment: @user3394380 [full text](http://ajcn.nutrition.org/content/55/6/1060.long) but note that at any pubmed reference, full text links are found at the top right of the screen layout.  Cheers.